# How to call a function in a form from another form?

Tags: 8, forms

I have 2 forms: `distribution_inscription_table_form` and `distribution_inscription_for_user_form` in the same custom module (`amap`).

```
namespace Drupal\amap\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class DistributionInscriptionTableForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'distribution_inscription_table_form';
  }
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    some code...
    $rows = $this->_listEnrolments();
    some code...
    return $form;
  }
  public function _listEnrolments() {
    some code...
    return $rows;
  }
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    some code...
  }
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    some code...
  }
}


namespace Drupal\amap\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class DistributionInscriptionForUserForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'distribution_inscription_for_user_form';
  }
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $rows = ????_listEnrolments(); <--------
    return $form;
  }
}
```

As they share a significant part of code; I put this code in a public function `_listEnrolments` located in the first form.
How can I call this function from the other form?

Comment: I've voted to close the question because this is not Drupal specific. When you have two classes which share a significant part of code then the most obvious OOP way would be to extend both from a common base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As they share a significant part of code; I put this code in a public function _listEnrolments located in the first form.

If it's functionality that two classes share equally, neither class should own it; it should be in a service, and the service should be injected into each form class. Otherwise you'll have to do something pretty awkward (and not good practice) to get an instance of the form class which implements the method to work with.

The [Dependency Injection for a Form](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form) docs page should get you most of the rest of the way.

Comment: And/or a trait, but typically a service.

Comment: @Kevin could you clarify what you call a "trait"?

Comment: As in a PHP trait @gbmapo, a quick search for that term will tell you all about what they are and how to use them

Answer (score 2):

I created `amap.services.yml`

```
services:
  listenrolments:
    class: Drupal\amap\ListEnrolments
    arguments: []
```

and `ListEnrolments.php`

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\amap;
class ListEnrolments {
  public function __construct() {
  }
  public function list() {
    some code...
    return $rows;
    }
}
```

and in my two forms, inserted

```
$rows = \Drupal::service('listenrolments')->list();
```

at the right place.
And it works!